# Use PIL to convert a grayscale image to a (1, H, W) numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Using PIL to convert a RGB image to a (H, W, 3) numpy array is very fast.

```
im = np.array(PIL.open(path))
```

However, I cannot find a **fast** way to convert a grayscale image to a (H, W, 1) array. I tried two approaches but they are both much slower than above:

```
im = np.array(PIL.open(path)) # return an (H, W) array
im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)
im = im.astype(int)
```

This approach is slow too:

```
img = PIL.open(path)
im = np.array(img.getdata()).reshape(img.size[1], img.size[0], 1)
```

Please advice...

Comment: Any particular reason for using `int` dtype as the final dtype and not `uint8` or similar ones? We could optimize a lot if lowered-precision/unsigned dtypes are okay.

Comment: @Divakar thank you for the answer and help. The data type (value) of the grayscale file is int (0 ~ 255)...

Comment: Well that sounds like `uint8`. So, I would suggest using `dtype=np.uint8` in that case.

Comment: Also, `np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)` is appending new axis at the start, so its `(1,H,W)`, while the second code is doing so at the end : `(H,W,1)`. Which one's correct?

Comment: (1, H, W) is exactly what I want (just edit the title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.asarray()` to get the array view, then append a new axis with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then use type conversion with `copy` set to `False` (in case you were converting from same dtype to save on memory) -

```
im = np.asarray(PIL.open(path))
im_out = im[None].astype(dtype=int, copy=False)
```

This appends new axis at the start, resulting in `(1,H,W)` as the output array shape. To do so, for the end to get an array shape of `(H,W,1)`, do : `im[...,None]` instead of `im[None]`.

---

A simpler way would be -

```
im_out = np.asarray(img, dtype=int)[None]
```

If the input is already in `uint8` dtype and we want an output array of the same dtype, use `dtype=np.uint8` and that should be pretty fast.